# query to get results from mongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the following collections in MongoDB

```
 "userDetails" : [
        { 
            "user" : DBRef("users", "RAVI"), 
            "class1" : DBRef("classes", "1"), 
            "class2" : DBRef("classes", "2")
        }, 
        { 
            "user" : DBRef("users", "TEJA"), 
            "class1" : DBRef("classes", "1"), 
            "class2" : DBRef("classes", "2")
        }]

    classes
        {
          "_id" : "1",
          "maxScore" : "50",
          "subject" :  DBRef("subjects", "class1")
    }
    { 
        "_id" : "2",
          "maxScore" : "80",
          "subject" :  DBRef("subjects", "class2")
    }
    users{
    "_id" : "RAVI",
    "address" : "3-2-2222",
    "lastClass" : "1"
    "lastScore" : ""
    }
    {
    "_id" : "TEJA",
    "address" : "5-23",
    "lastClass" : "1"
    }
```

From java program, I want to query such that when I pass input as user name I want to fetch all the details of that user and his classes details.can anyone help me out with this?
previously i tried

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("userDetails", 1).append("userDetails", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("user.$id", "RAVI")));
        BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(new BasicDBObject(), fields);
        List<UserDetails> usrDetailsList = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserDetails.class);
```

Comment: What  have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Considering you have data inserted in your collection, now this following code will fetch a specific record from collection:

  BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();

  whereQuery.put("user","RAVI");  //here you are specifying that you want all details of user-RAVI

  DBCursor cursor = collection.find(whereQuery);

 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(cursor.next());
 }
```

Comment: I am getting an error near collection.find() indicating cannot find symbol collection.What is collection here

Comment: collection here is the object of class DBCollection where it refers to your collection(table) in mongodb database.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution with a minor change.I removed `$` symbol before id and i got my answer

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("userDetails", 1).append("userDetails", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("user.id", "RAVI")));
    BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(new BasicDBObject(), fields);
    List<UserDetails> usrDetailsList = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserDetails.class);
```

but i got stuck in another point.I want to search my query based on subject id something like following

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("userDetails", 1).append("userDetails", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("class1.$subject.$id", "class1")));
    BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(new BasicDBObject(), fields);
    List<UserDetails> usrDetailsList = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserDetails.class);
```